# Convincing a non-tech company to contribute to open source, legal hangups

Tags: software-industry

I work for a fairly large US company that does a good deal of internal software development, although we are not a software/tech company. The vast majority of what we do stays inside, with only a small percentage seeing any kind of outside distribution. I've recently had some success making an internal push to allow employees to contribute to open source projects and things are almost there. Management has asked for some additional information and I'm not sure where to find it.

They don't seem to have a problem with the idea of employees contributing to open source as a side project as long as it's relevant to our business (small, internal side projects are already allowed). It may even be possible that we'll start a few of our own open source projects (although the core software likely won't leave, there may be some miscellaneous bits and pieces that others would find useful), but that's a bit out of scope for the time being. The hangup at this point is potential liability, not just for our own projects, but for employee contributions.

I've explained that most licenses have a liability clause, but they're looking for something more broad. I'm having a devil of a time digging out any resources on this subject. Most articles/papers are about companies using open source software commercially or other potential hangups with developers contributing on behalf of the company. I can find virtually nothing going over possible legal ramifications of contributing to open source. This is probably because there are few outside of license-violating issues (ie, contributing code from one project to a different one with an incompatible license or contributing copyrighted IP), but I can't even find something explaining that. There are plenty of articles going over many other areas of this subject, but there's little on the subject of detailed potential legal pitfalls.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Even a good article about a (preferably non-tech) company making the decision and their analysis could be useful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you can find... Saying "Use at your own risk" doesn't cover all potential legal issues, but would cover most. If you openly said "Hey this is free, it probably has bugs, these bugs could potentially cost you money and productivity. By using this software you are agreeing to accept all consequences and liability... etc" (only written in lawyer) that would cover almost everything except in such cases where you created obvious malicious code. (I'm not a lawyer, you should talk to one for proper advice)

Comment: Are you working on these open source side projects during company time?

Comment: Nobody is doing this yet, but the idea is that employees are allowed to devote a small amount of their time on the clock to open source projects as long as it is approved by a manager.

Comment: I have never heard of a company ever getting sued or in any other legal trouble for participating in open source projects where there is an open source license. Does anyone have an instance of this? The only case I can think of was Oracle vs Google but that was distinctly NOT for open source transgressions. Perhaps the _real_ danger is inadvertently "violating" a copyright or silly patent and having some aggressive competitor use that as a pretext to give roomfuls of lawyers something fun to work on?

Comment: Are you talking about releasing internally-written projects as open source? Or about contributing back changes and improvements made internally to existing open source code which you use? Or both?

Comment: It would be both. Initially, I'm just hoping to get a greenlight on contributions to existing projects, but I'm also aiming for the company to create their own open source projects as well.

Answer (score 5):

Your company is asking you to do the work of a lawyer. You should recommend to them to consult an open-source software lawyer and maybe provide a few such lawyers they can contact (after doing some research on good lawyers).

Unfortunately, to me, it sounds like you have done all that is required to make the case for allowing open source development. Most likely, your company is going to keep asking you for more and more and more, just because eventually you will be forced to make lawyer-like claims but you may not have the specifics down and something will eventually come off sounding ambiguous enough that someone can squelch this idea of contributing to open source.

I've seen this time and again in more bureaucratic companies (and almost always "fairly large US company" == "bureaucracy"). The idea is for higher-ups to merely pay lip-service to the idea of open source software, because after all, who wants to be seen as the anti-open-source villain? But their duplicitous true attitude is that they don't want to fiddle with the legal overhead to make it happen -- generally not because they have actually done any legitimate cost-benefit analysis and can truly say, with numbers, why such open source projects would be net bad for the company, but rather because they have Dilberty, pointy-headed and uninformed opinions about worker productivity and the usefulness of side projects, or because they are simply extremely risk averse and just don't care about assessing the benefits: they just want to avoid any risk of their firm looking bad or being legally culpable for participation in a side project. Sometimes they also want to have blanket, draconian intellectual property policies, so that if one of their employees makes Minecraft in her spare time, they retain the rights to it.

Anyway, I wouldn't be surprised if, even though you believe they are close to accepting the idea, the reality is that they are miles away and are sending you on a legalese wild goose chase just to find some ambiguity loop hole that creates enough of a sound bite in their meetings that they can squelch this idea.

Answer (score 0):

**IANAL**

Nothing is 100% risk free. A patent troll targets the project, your company might end up named in a lawsuit. But that risk is not more than that held by any user of the project, whether they contribute or not.

Contributing does in theory open you up to liability if the project causes problems. But that is highly unlikely .. I don;t think that this kind of suit has ever been filed.

You should look at the various open source licenses, pick one that you think appropriate, and give it to management as a suggestion. Look for the most serious "hold harmless" or other such clause which preclude the user from claiming liability against a contributor.

This is a great resource ... https://tldrlegal.com/